# XAMPP MySQL have started to shuts down unexpectedly when opening one page

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

**Hello! :D**

I'm making a website for the fun of it and after leaving the work for a few hours, when I returned back I get an unexpected shutdown error every time that I open one of the pages of the website.

Other pages where the database is used are working fine, the exact page I'm having a problem with also worked as it should last time I was working on it... I have tried changing back the most recent changes in the PHP files without any result.

I have tried everything that doesn't sound like it may ruin the database that I could find after about 2-3h trying to solve this, copying the backup folder and the data folder to make a new data folder and the error is still there.
I can't find any other program using the same port, which shouldn't even be the problem since it works for all other pages of the website...

**Errors:**

XAMPP Control Panel:

```
22:09:48  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
22:09:48  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
22:09:48  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
22:09:48  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
22:09:48  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
22:09:48  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
22:09:48  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

MySQL Logs:

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=1238359
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.13 started; log sequence number 1238368; transaction id 2064
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\XAMMP\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-07-11 22:25:31 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Website Errors/Warnings:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute(): MySQL server has gone away in D:\XAMMP\htdocs\XXX(Censored)XXX\includes\functionsStatInter.inc.php on line 60

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute(): Error reading result set's header in D:\XAMMP\htdocs\XXX(Censored)XXX\includes\functionsStatInter.inc.php on line 60

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\XAMMP\htdocs\XXX(Censored)XXX\includes\functionsStatInter.inc.php:68 Stack trace: #0 D:\XAMMP\htdocs\XXX(Censored)XXX\includes\functionsStatInter.inc.php(68): mysqli_num_rows(false) #1 D:\XAMMP\htdocs\XXX(Censored)XXX\statistics_interactive.php(60): AmountRuns2() #2 {main} thrown in D:\XAMMP\htdocs\XXX(Censored)XXX\includes\functionsStatInter.inc.php on line 68
```

Any more information needed? Please tell me if you feel I missed something!

=====

**UPDATE 12/7-2021**

When I was going to try the suggestions from the comments, I found out that now I can't load anything that has to do whit the database at all...
Nothing of the things suggested in the error has ever been changed.

Error from PhPMyAdmin:

```
MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.
 mysqli::real_connect(): MySQL server has gone away
 mysqli::real_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=19092
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
 mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.
```

=====

**UPDATE 12/7-2021 (a few hours later)**

The problem I got in the last update seems to be that I tried things that were suggested to solve the problem that I have found in other places and I probably messed something up.
So I changed back everything to as it was before, will start working on how to solve the main problem that I asked about from the beginning now. :D

=====

**UPDATE 13/7-2021**

Haha, wow... it seems like the problem was me being stupid all the time... :P

So the problem was that I use "?" to replace some values in the SQL code, this is set by sessions that themselves are set by a form.
So when the sessions were reset, I had not yet added a default that is used if they aren't set... so this was what caused the problem all along.

**Thanks so much for all help anyway! :D <3**

Comment: thisis normal log and shows a running  server, how do you cnnect and what are you running, there are sometime_out you can increase

Comment: You will need a complete stack trace to track down the exact PHP script with line number that is causing this. Also, from life experience, this mostly happens when a query becomes too of an overload for the MySQL. Check your queries carefully, especially long running queries with loads of data.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean, didn't really get what you are trying to tell me except that the MySQL logs are normal. @nbk

Comment: Is there anything that can be done to not make it overload the MySQL? And do you have an idea why it worked when I was testing when making it but not a few hours later? @BrokenArrow

Comment: @eke0909 It is not realistic for any of us to realize why it worked before and what went wrong now just by looking at those pieces of logs there mate :) But most likely, it is a query issue, I suspect you have dynamically generated SQL for some lengthy operation? I think you need to execute each query in MySQL Workbench to see which one is the culprit.

Comment: Ohh, didn't think about that but when I do it's quite obvious it's hard for you to know that. Thanks for the answer, will try that out tomorrow! @BrokenArrow

Comment: I was going to test what you wrote yesterday, but now when I was opened phpMyAdmin I got the error I added in the question. Any idea why this could happen and what to do? @BrokenArrow

Comment: Check your MySQL server is running.

Comment: It is, but it crashes with the same error as the one I only got when opening one of the pages earlier. @BrokenArrow

Comment: Stop all your websites, start only the MySQL server and try accessing it with MySQL Workbench. Upon that, try repairing databases.

Comment: It seems like it crashes by itself now, about 15s after I start the server it crashes. From the beginning, it was first when I opened anything that had to do with that page... Should I try and repair the database, if so, how do I do that? @BrokenArrow

Comment: You cannot repair the database if MySQL server is not up

Comment: You can try starting up MySQL in recovery mode though, search Google how to start MySQL in recovery mode.

Comment: Okay, will try that! @BrokenArrow

Comment: I have not tried the last thing you wrote since I have been doing other things, but I just came and think about that this probably happened when I tried to copy the original data folder, make a new one and then move things from the old data folder and the backup folder to the new one.
If this was the problem, is there anything else I should try before the last thing you wrote? @BrokenArrow

Comment: Bad idea :( You should have use the EXPORT <=> IMPORT method with phpMyAdmin. I think, if you have an SQL backup of the database, you can start it from the scratch :) Or can try removing the corresponding data files (remember I said if you had the backup).

Comment: The reason for me trying that solution to solve the first error when I opened the one page.
So you are saying that like 95% of the solutions of similar things on the internet are bad ideas because I tried to do that just before I wrote this problem. So if I don't have a recent backup (I saved the old data file by renaming it and then making a new one, is this enough as a backup?), everything in the database is gone!?
What do you mean by removing the corresponding data files? @BrokenArrow

Comment: You can restore back the data files, I think, if you can ensure the correct version of MySQL version the data files belonged to, this should work, depending on you have the same OS/environment (this is not a rigid case, but this guarantees success). Of course that is a bad idea, otherwise MySQL won't facilitate you with database export/import functionality, it costed time/energy/effort for the MySQL team to develop that feature for you.

Comment: Ohh, just thought I would try and add back the old data folder and it seems like it won't crash just after a few seconds anymore! :D

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry for making things more confusing than was needed, will try every SQL code for the page that makes it crash to see if I can find what is the problem. @BrokenArrow <3

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I managed to solve it after testing deleting some things and then came to think about what I wrote in the question update. @BrokenArrow <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was not any real answer posted, even though I had a helpful conversation in the comments I thought that I maybe should post an answer myself since I managed to solve everything after trying out a few tips from the comments that helped me on the way to solve this.

**Solution:**

So the problem was that I use "?" to replace some values in the SQL code, this is set by sessions that themselves are set by a form. So when the sessions were automatically reset after some time, I had not yet added a default that is used if they aren't set... so this was what caused the problem all along.

**Why?**

That explains why it worked as it supposed to do one day to start crashing when trying to access the page a day later without me changing anything.

Thanks for all the help, it guided me to test every SQL segment one by one and all of them worked as supposed to.
This got me thinking about it was something else, so I removed all but one thing connected to the database and everyone made it crash just by themselves.
Then I came and think about that it maybe was that the sessions were not working, so I removed everything that had to do with the database, filled in the form and then saved it so that the sessions were made.
When I then added all connections to the database back, everything worked just as it should.

**Once again, thanks for the help! :D**